# make changes in gridview without using database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, data-binding, gridview

I have a gridview... which is not using a database.

I have these 3 rows of which are fixed and when the user clicks on the add button a new row is created .
The grid view looks like this

> **employee department ||timeorwork  ||Delete**
>
> admin  |||[dropdownlist] ||[dropdownlist]
>   button  // so this row is fixed and i
>   start adding after this row

how do i do this...
sorry but i am not good at editing.. i tried my best..
sorry again
what is the best way to solve my prob

Comment: how are the changes persisted?

Comment: the changes are not permanent but temperory.. they should be removed when i leave the page

Answer (score 1):

Bind your GridView to a DataTable.  When the user adds a row, add a row to the DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an ObjectDataSource and keep your data in memory. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx) (and following) for details.